# TypeError : object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently learned Python. I can't catch the error in this code. What is wrong?

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self  = [initial_balance, 0]

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Withdraws the amount from the account.  Each withdrawal resulting in a
        negative balance also deducts a penalty fee of 5 dollars from the balance.
        """
        self[0] -= amount
        if self[0] < 0:
            self[0] -= 5

        self[1] += 1

    def get_balance(self):
        """Returns the current balance in the account."""
        return self[0]

    def get_fees(self):
        """Returns the total fees ever deducted from the account."""
        return 5*self[1]


my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\bank.py", line 28, in <module>
    my_account.withdraw(15)
  File "C:\Python34\bank.py", line 15, in withdraw
    self[0] -= amount + 5
TypeError: 'BankAccount' object does not support indexing
```

`self` value contains `initial_balance` and a count of how many withdrawals have happened.

Comment: You are doing Python OOP completely wrong. I suggest you read [the tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). Also, could you please review the indentation in your question?

Comment: only short suggestion before my eyes start to bleed, try to use `self.account` in all places where you wrote `self` (except the 1st argument in each method of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
class BankAccount:

    OVERDRAW_PENALTY = 5

    def __init__(self, opening_balance=0):
        self.balance = opening_balance
        self.withdrawals = 0

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.withdrawals += 1
        self.balance -= amount
        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance -= self.OVERDRAW_PENALTY
        return amount
```

Note that I am using `self` to access *instance and class attributes*, not trying to assign directly to it. Also, I have factored out the "magic number" `5`, so it is clearer what is happening.

Also, your implementation of `get_fees` is incorrect - the number of withdrawals is currently incremented *whether or not a fee is applied*. You should either store a `self.overdrawn_withdrawals` count separately or keep a running total `self.fees` attribute.

Finally, I have added `return amount` to the end of `withdraw` - this allows you to do things like:

```
account2.deposit(account1.withdraw(100))
```

to easily transfer money between `BankAccount`s.

Answer (score 3):

self always refers to the object that calls the class function. So, it is recommended not to assign something to the self variable like:

```
self = #something
```

in the constructor.  Give that variable a name. Like:

```
self.details = [initialbalance,0]
```

And use the variable name wherever.

Comment: Well you *can*, but you probably shouldn't! Also, separate attributes `self.balance` and `self.withdrawals` would be more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the BankAccount object. You need to assign and reference instance variables.

Your `__init__()` method should be something like this:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        """Creates an account with the given balance."""
        self.balance  = initial_balance
        self.fees = 0
        self.withdrawals = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposits the amount into the account."""
        self.balance += amount
```

Similarly `withdraw()` and `get_balance()` should reference `self.balance`, and `get_fees()` should reference `self.fees`.